# RIA Services Web.config default configuration

Tags: iis, web-config, wcf-ria-services, integrated-pipeline-mode

When I install RIA Services with NuGet (Version 4.1.60730), the default Web.config registeres the domain service module under both  and .

This works fine with the development server in Visual Studio 2010, but the standard configuration of the full IIS complains about the setting being incorrect for integrated pipeline mode.

Commenting out the registration under system.web fixes the issue there, but then it won't run under the development server.

Is there a configuration that works in both cases? If not, how to go around this problem?

I know I could install RIA Services system-wide, but I'd like to move away from that.

Comment: Can you use a web.debug.config and web.release.config to work around this?  It doesn't seem like this should be specific to RIA Services.

Comment: @JeffHandley I could but that would be slightly annoying. I found another way and answered my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to disable the complaint about spurious entries in system.web. Put

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

in system.webServer.